# Import Highcharts and highcharts-more (AngularJS 1.5 + TypeScript + webpack)

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to use Highcharts with some of its extensions (like "highcharts-more") in a project that uses webpack, TypeScript and AngularJS (version 1.5).

I've installed Highcharts through npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts), but I'm not able to import the extensions that come with it.

The actual trick I'm doing is to set some global variables in the webpack config file

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Highcharts: 'highcharts',
        HighchartsMore: 'highcharts/highcharts-more',
        HighchartsExporting: 'highcharts/modules/exporting'
    })
]
```

and extending Highcharts manually

```
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
```

without any import in between. With this non-ideal solution TypeScript is complaining because

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HighchartsMore'
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HighchartsExporting'
```

In particular with Highcharts there is no error. Which I guess has to do with the fact that Highcharts is the only thing I manage to import, via

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

which I can substitute with the Highchart global declaration in the webpack config. What I would like is to import every module in a clean way, something like

```
import {HighchartsMore} from 'highcharts-more';
```

Any idea is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This type of error can occur when you do not have definition files for exported variables. Those Highcharts extensions still require them - you might want to read more about importing modules without d.ts here: https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-static-templates/issues/9 - it might change in the future.

You need to create a d.ts file for the extensions. For highcharts-more this is my file:

```
/// <reference path="index.d.ts" />

declare var HighchartsMore: (H: HighchartsStatic) => HighchartsStatic;

declare module "highcharts/highcharts-more" {
    export = HighchartsMore;
}
```

reference path points to standard DefinietelyTyped Highcharts file from here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts
It allows to use type from Highcharts.d.ts because initializing will need proper typing for initializing extension:

```
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
```

And finally don't forget to include all d.ts files by defining tsconfig or  writing reference path in your files.

Comment: Thanks! I've created a pull request for that: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/10649

Answer (score 2):

remove these lines from webpack.config.js:

`plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Highcharts: 'highcharts',
        HighchartsMore: 'highcharts/highcharts-more',
        HighchartsExporting: 'highcharts/modules/exporting'
    })
]`

install typings file for highcharts using this:

`npm install --save @types/highcharts`

change your import statements to following:

`import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsMore = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);`